# Struct errors with mazes

Tags: c, pointers, struct, maze

I am writing a program to read a maze from a text file and pass it through some structs. It is supposed to go through the structs get read out line by line finding errors if the maze is too short or contains an odd character inside of it. Once it passes all the requirements it then is printed out, but with a border surrounding it with( - and | ).

However there were some errors, I first had the "function declaration is not allowed here" error. So I moved the whole program above main and got more errors. I feel like it is because of the parentheses that I might need to fix. I was also noticing that in some areas it would not recognize iRows which was initialized inside of a struct. Not exactly sure what is going on there since it is recognizing iCols just fine.

When I am calling CELL into my first struct why is it not recognizing it at all? Do I need to make it an int or define it as a struct so it can read it?

I Still am trying to debug everything just thought I would bring it over to have some insight. Some of my pointers are not working and I have gone through and fixed some errors, I just can't seem to be able to fix these ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MQnode {
    CELL **ppCE;
    int iRows, iCols, iGoals, iStarts;
}MAZE;

typedef struct CEnode {
    char cglyph;

}CELL;

MAZE *
ReadMaze(FILE *fpIn)
{
    register int j, k, c;
    register MAZE *pMQRet;

    if ((MAZE *)0 == pMQRet = malloc(sizeof(MAZE)*1)) {
        if (2 != fscanf(fpIn, " %d,%d\n", &pMQRet->iRows, &pMQRet->iCols))  {
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (2 > pMQRet->iRows || 2 > pMQRet->iCols) {
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if ((CELL *)0 == (pMQRet->ppCE = malloc(sizeof(CELL *)*iRows))) {
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        //intialize goals and starts

        for (j=0; j<iRows;++j){
            if ((CELL*)0 == pMQRet->ppCE[j] = malloc((pMQRet->iCols+1)* sizeof(CELL))){
                EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            for (k=0; k<pMQRet->iCols+1;++k){
                if (EOF ==(c = fgetc(fpIn))){
                    EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

            }
        }ppCE[j][k] = c;
    }
}return pMQRet;


void
PrintMaze(FILE *fpout, MAZE *pMQThis)
{
    register int j,k,l;
    register CELL *pCE;
    if ((MAZE *)0 == pMQThis){
        exit(0);
    }
    for (l=0;l<pMQThis->iCols+2;++1)
        fputc('-',fpout);
    for (j=0;j<pMQThis->iRows;++j){
        pCE = pMQThis->ppCE[j];
        fputc('|',fpout);
        for (k=0; k<pMQThis->iCols;++k)
            fputc(pCE[k], cglyph,fpout);
    }
    fputc('|',fpout);
    fputc('\n',fpout);
}
fputc('-',fpout);
return pCE;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


}//end of main
```

Comment: You have statements outside of functions. You need a good C book.

Comment: Any recommendations for one online? I am doing this for a class and we are not really using a book at all. However I think I am making some good progress went from 10 errors to 6 now.

Comment: A hint: drop the "register" keywords.  They're rarely needed, and probably aren't doing what you think they're doing.  They're also causing a lot of your [compiler errors](http://ideone.com/sVzwWy).

Comment: You should define CELL ( which is basically... a char?) before using it in MAZE. In ReadMaze the condition `(MAZE *)0 == pMQRet = malloc(sizeof(MAZE)*1)` is nonsense, use malloc (without *1) before the if and then check for `!pMQRet` otherwise you will execute the if branch whith a null pointer, and what is EXIT_FAILURE?

Comment: @Mags IMO there aren't really any good C books online. If you plan to really get into C, you should read [the c programming language](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Brian-W-Kernighan/dp/0131103628) and friends

Comment: I will definitely take a look at these books. @Bob__ When using Xcode I was going to just exit 0; It auto filled it with EXIT_FAILURE, so I just went with it for now. I assumed it was almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can decipher, this rework of your code should compile -- I'm not saying it should work, but it should compile and give you a leg up on a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct CEnode {
    char cglyph;
} CELL;

typedef struct MQnode {
    CELL **ppCE;
    int iRows, iCols, iGoals, iStarts;
} MAZE;

MAZE *
ReadMaze(FILE *fpIn)
{
    int j, k, c;
    MAZE *pMQRet;

    if ((MAZE *)0 == (pMQRet = malloc(sizeof(MAZE))))
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (2 != fscanf(fpIn, " %d,%d\n", &pMQRet->iRows, &pMQRet->iCols))
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (2 > pMQRet->iRows || 2 > pMQRet->iCols)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((CELL **)0 == (pMQRet->ppCE = malloc(sizeof(CELL *) * pMQRet->iRows)))
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // initialize goals and starts

    for (j = 0; j < pMQRet->iRows; j++)
    {
        if ((CELL*)0 == (pMQRet->ppCE[j] = malloc(sizeof(CELL) * pMQRet->iCols + 1)))
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (k = 0; k < pMQRet->iCols + 1; k++)
        {
            if (EOF == (c = fgetc(fpIn)))
            {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            pMQRet->ppCE[j][k].cglyph = c;
        }
    }

    return pMQRet;
}

void
PrintMaze(FILE *fpout, MAZE *pMQThis)
{
    int j, k, l;
    CELL *pCE;

    if ((MAZE *)0 == pMQThis)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (l = 0; l < pMQThis->iCols + 2; l++)
    {
        fputc('-', fpout);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < pMQThis->iRows; j++)
    {
        pCE = pMQThis->ppCE[j];

        fputc('|', fpout);

        for (k = 0; k < pMQThis->iCols; k++)
        {
            fputc(pCE[k].cglyph, fpout);
        }

        fputc('|', fpout);
        fputc('\n', fpout);
    }

    for (l = 0; l < pMQThis->iCols + 2; l++)
    {
        fputc('-', fpout);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

} // end of main
```

My recommendation is you write and test smaller blocks of code as you build up to larger ones.  Good luck.

Comment: I can see some issues that I was having from my original code post. I thank you for the structuring of all this. If I have those functions above main, but I wanted to make a call to open up the actual file would I call something from PrintMaze or ReadMaze? I was trying to call down *fpIn to open, however it was not opening any of the files. Would I instead need to call the whole function down to open up the file using argv[ ]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I would expect `main()` or something it invokes to call `ReadMaze()` once to read in the maze.  (Assuming there is only one maze, otherwise your game controller function might call `ReadMaze()` on every new game.)  I suggest you close off this question as answered and open a new one, if needed, with your question and what code you have so far to control the actual play of the game.  You can still reference this question for those who need more detail.